# Como desativar console.log de determinado arquivo js?

Tags: javascript

Tenho muitos comandos `console.log` em um arquivo `regras.js`.
Gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de desabitar o `console.log` **apenas** nesse arquivo, já que comentar cada console.log seria muito demorado, pois tem muitos.

**Observações:**

**Já utilizei esse recurso:**

Mas não me serve já que ele desabilita o *`console.log`* de todos os arquivos.

> console.log = function() {}

Comment: Comenta todos os `console.log` com um `replace all` do notepad++.. em menos de 10 segundos vc faz isso

Comment: console.log não é tipo break point que vc pode fazer um toggle de all para desativar/ativar você pode utilizar algum editor de texto para buscar e substituir estas ocorrencias se você fizer console.log replace // console.log tudo vai estar comentado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adicione ao final do seu arquivo `regras.js` a seguinte linha:

```
console.clear();
```

Isso limpará todos os `console.log()` executados. Pode ser uma boa solução, caso você não queira ou não possa comentar todas as linhas.

Answer (score 4):

No início do seu arquivo faça:

```
var __log = console.log;
console.log = function() {};
```

E no fim dele restaure `console.log` com:

```
console.log = __log;
```

Answer (score 0):

Programaticamente, eu não conheco uma maneira.

Mas utilizando o `replace all` de qualquer IDE é possível. Busque por `console.log` e substitua por `//console.log`